# How to run a build command with CircleCI Node/Express app

Tags: circleci

I have a backend API via Node/Express and am just starting to learn CI/CD.  I am using CircleCI and have a general template set up but can't seem to figure out how to get CircleCi to create a build folder during the process.

Below is my starting `circle.yml` file:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.9.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "npm installing"
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
  test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.9.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "Running test suite (TODO not currently applicable)"
  complete:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.9.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "Completed build & test process (TODO Add linting checks)"
workflows:
  version: 2.1
  build_test:
    jobs:
      - build
```

I have a `build` script in my `package.json` with the following: `"build": "tsc"`.
Running this outside of circleci, it compiles the build folder as I need.
Looking at the status on circleci, everything passes.  But the branch does not have the actual build folder.

Answer (score 0):

```js
version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.9.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "npm installing"
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/project
          paths:
            - build
  test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.9.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "Running test suite (TODO not currently applicable)"
  complete:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.9.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "Completed build & test process (TODO Add linting checks)"
  deploy:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:12.9.1
    steps:
    - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/project
    - run:
        name: Deployment Step
        command: |
          #!/bin/sh
          ls build
workflows:
  version: 2.1
  build_test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
      - complete:
          requires:
            - test
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - complete
```

When the build script runs, creates a folder called build that you can persist in order to use in another job. In the new job called deploy, it calls the folder where the build folder is, so now you can for example send this folder to a server.